# Proving "$\{s_{n}\}$ converges to L" is false iff $\exists c>0$ such that $|s_{n}-L|>c$ for infinitely many $n$

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to prove the following proposition.

**Proposition 1.** Let $\{s_{n}\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. The statement "$\{s_{n}\}$ converges to L" is false if and only if there is a positive number $c$ so that the inequality $$|s_{n}-L|>c$$ holds for infinitely many values of n.

I disposed of the converse by contradiction. That is, I assumed that there is a positive number $c$  so that the inequality $$|s_{n}-L|>c$$ holds for infinitely many values of $n$, and $\{s_{n}\}$ converges to L. From these assumptions, it was relatively easy to deduce a contradiction.

I am stuck, however, on the forward direction. I am attempting to argue by contradiction again, so I have begun the proof in the following way:

*Proof.* $(\implies)$ Assume, to the contrary, that "$\{s_{n}\}$ converges to $L$" is false and for every $c>0$, the inequality $$|s_{n}-L|>c$$ holds for only finitely many values of $n$.

Let $c>0$ be given. Since $|s_{n}-L|>c$ holds for only finitely many $n$, let $N$ be the largest integer for which $|s_{n}-L|>c$ holds. Then $n>N$ implies $$|s_{n}-L| \leq c.$$

But this is where I am stuck. I am trying to deduce that $\{s_{n}\}$ converges to $L$, which would contradict my assumptions. But in order to prove convergence, I need to show that for every $c>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|s_{n}-L|<c$. From what I have been able to deduce, I can show that for every $c>0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|s_{n}-L| \leq c$, but I cannot see how to make this inequality strict.

I thought about breaking it into three cases:

1. $|s_{n}-L|=c$ for no values of $n$.
2. $|s_{n}-L|=c$ for finitely many values of $n$.
3. $|s_{n}-L|=c$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

In this approach, cases 1 and 2 are easy enough, but I do not see how to handle case 3. Furthermore, this approach seems overly complicated, which makes me think I missed a simple more elegant path.

Hints and/or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I cannot see how to make this inequality strict." Let $c>0$. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $|s_n-L|\le \epsilon$. Take $\epsilon=c/2$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it easier to just assume that $\{s_{n}\}$ converges to $L$ is false and then conclude that for infinitely many $n$ there exists $c>0$ such that $|s_{n}-L|>c$.

Comment: I thought about doing this as well, but I was having difficulty with negating the definition of convergence. The definition I am working with is: $\forall \varepsilon$, $\exists N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|s_{n}-L|< \varepsilon$. Would the following be the correct negation: $\exists\varepsilon >0$ such that $\forall N$, $n \geq N$ implies $|s_{n}-L|\geq \varepsilon$.

Comment: I believe the negation of the definition of convergene is $\exists\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$ $\exists n>N$ such that $|s_{n}-L|>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

($s_n$ converges to $L$) is false $\ \Longleftrightarrow\ $ ($\forall c>0,\ \exists N \in \mathbb{N},\ \forall n > N \colon\ |s_n-L| \leqslant c$) is false $\ \Longleftrightarrow\ $ $\exists c>0,\ \forall N \in \mathbb{N},\ \exists n > N \colon\ |s_n-L|>c$ $\ \Longleftrightarrow\ $ $\exists c$ so that the inequality $|s_{n}-L|>c$ holds for infinitely many values of n.